# Calculate data attributes and output into HTML

Tags: jquery

I want to calculate all `<select>` data attributes and output the total into a `<span>`.

Here are the selects:

```
<select name="product-1" id="product-1">
    <option value="0" data-price="0">0 (0.00$)</option>
    <option value="10" data-price="52.39">10 (52.39$)</option>
    <option value="20" data-price="61.93">20 (61.93$)</option>
</select>
<select name="product-2" id="product-2">
    <option value="0" data-price="0">0 (0.00$)</option>
    <option value="10" data-price="57.92">10 (57.92$)</option>
    <option value="20" data-price="77.81">20 (77.81$)</option>
</select>
<select name="product-3" id="product-3">
    <option value="0" data-price="0">0 (0.00$)</option>
    <option value="10" data-price="64.63">10 (64.63$)</option>
    <option value="20" data-price="84.07">20 (84.07$)</option>
</select>
```

Here is the span:

```
<span id="total">4.99</span>
```

Here is the jQuery:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        delivery = 4.99, $("select").change(function() {
            total = $(this).find("option:selected").data("price") + delivery, $("#total").html(total.toFixed(2))
        })
    });
```

The problem:
I can't figure it out, how to sum all of the `<select>` attributes into one total. With my current code, it only output's the last changed option.

Comment: You need to go through all of select so something like `$('select option').each(function() { ... })`  + you are just changing the value you forgot to sum it with a `+=`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to loop through the selected options of each `select` when a value is changed and keep a running total of the selected prices. Try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var delivery = 4.99;

  $("select").change(function() {
    var total = delivery;
    $('select option:selected').each(function() {
      total += parseFloat($(this).data('price'));
    });
    $("#total").html(total.toFixed(2))
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="product-1" id="product-1">
  <option value="0" data-price="0">0 (0.00$)</option>
  <option value="10" data-price="52.39">10 (52.39$)</option>
  <option value="20" data-price="61.93">20 (61.93$)</option>
</select>
<select name="product-2" id="product-2">
  <option value="0" data-price="0">0 (0.00$)</option>
  <option value="10" data-price="57.92">10 (57.92$)</option>
  <option value="20" data-price="77.81">20 (77.81$)</option>
</select>
<select name="product-3" id="product-3">
  <option value="0" data-price="0">0 (0.00$)</option>
  <option value="10" data-price="64.63">10 (64.63$)</option>
  <option value="20" data-price="84.07">20 (84.07$)</option>
</select>


<span id="total">4.99</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

This the even fires whenever any of the selects is changed but it will only give you the price of the one you just changed. Since you will always want the total of all 3 try using this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    delivery = 4.99, $("select").change(function() {
        total = delivery;
        $("select.product").each(function(){
            total+=$(this).find("option:selected").data("price");
        });
        $("#total").html(total.toFixed(2))
    })
});
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mt156j8m/)